# How to extend the plugin for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing the plugin for jQuery. I have the problem with the extension plugin. I wrote the plugin for example: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.

See the following example code:

```
(function($){
    var i18n    = {};
    var methods = {};
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
        //...
   };
})(jQuery);
```

How can I extend the property `i18n`?

I want to be able to support the internationalization plug-in settings which are stored in the separate file. How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
// plugin definition
$.fn.hilight = function(options) {
  // Extend our default options with those provided.
  // Note that the first arg to extend is an empty object -
  // this is to keep from overriding our "defaults" object.
  var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.hilight.defaults, options);
  // Our plugin implementation code goes here.
};
// plugin defaults - added as a property on our plugin function
$.fn.hilight.defaults = {
  foreground: 'red',
  background: 'yellow'
};
```

From here http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern.

This is a very nice tutorial to get started with

Answer (score 1):

jQuery plugins usually extend options like this:

```
var i18nOpts = $.extend({}, i18n, options.i18n);
```

Docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options

This happens inside the plugin itself.

```
(function($){
    var i18n    = {};
    var methods = {};
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
        var i18nOpts = $.extend({}, i18n, options.i18n);
   };
})(jQuery);
```

`i18n` only exists inside that function, to extend it, you can now pass options to the plugin.

```
$('#myDiv').myPlugin({
    i18n: {
        option1: "value",
        option2: "Value2"
    }
});
```

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko: The `i18n` variable can only be accessed from inside the anonymous function it's inside.

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko: Do what?  What are you trying to do?  You can't access `i18n` from outside of that function.  You need to pass options to the plugin when you call it, and then use `$.extend` like I showed to extend it (from inside the plugin).

Comment: I understand, but I don't know how to do it, so that these settings are stored in the separate file.

I'll ask in another way: how best to organize support for internationalization?

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko: I think you should edit the question to describe your *real* question.

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko: Take a look at coder's answer.  You can have your separate file assign values to `$.fn.myPlugin.defaults`.

Comment: Should I store the settings of internationalization like `$.myPlugin.i18n`?

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko: If you load your settings file *after* your plugin, you can do `$.fn.myPlugin.i18n = {}` from your settings file.  Then in your plugin, you can read `$.fn.myPlugin.i18n`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a handy template I use for myself..

```
(function($){

var MyClass = function (element, options){

   this.options = $.extend({}, options);

   this.someFunction = function (){...}  //Public members

   var otherFunction = function(){...}   //Private members

   $(element).data('pluginInstance', this);   

}


$.fn.myPlugin = function(options){

    var myClassInstace = new MyClass(this, options);

    //Do other things with the object.
}

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by **$.extend( objectA, objectB )** method of jQuery. I reckon youl'd better start learning jquery plugin dev. from basic hello world tutorial such as this link http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/3/How-To-Make-jQuery-Plugin-jQuery-Plugin-Hello-World-.html
or Check this post over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11611732/1539647 or