# Evaluating an object false within a conditional

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose we have defined a queue object and we want to loop while there are items in the queue.

The obvious solution:

```
var queue = new Queue();
// populate queue
while (queue.size()) {
    queue.pop();
}
```

The desired form:

```
var queue = new Queue();
// populate queue
while (queue) { // should stop when queue's size is 0
    queue.pop();
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this (exact) syntax showed in the second example javascript? If so, how?

Comment: why would you want to do that? You have to destruct your object to achieve this, because objects are always truthy, so you have to set it to null or undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve this (exact) syntax

My answer is: No.

I tried the following to solve the riddle, and it doesn't seem to work.
Yet I think this is the way to go.

Disclaimer: this is just some puzzle-solving, and not the real-world code.

```
var Queue = function () {};
Queue.prototype.sizeValue = 2;
Queue.prototype.size = function () 
{
    return this.sizeValue;
};
Queue.prototype.pop = function () 
{
    // EDIT: yes, it's not popping anything.
    // it just reduces size to make toString()
    // and valueOf() return nulls.
    this.sizeValue -= 1;
};
Queue.prototype.valueOf = function () 
{
    if (this.size() > 0) {
        return this.sizeValue;
    }
    return null;
};
Queue.prototype.toString = function () 
{
    if (this.size() > 0) {
        return "Queue["+this.sizeValue+"]";
    }
    return null;
};


var test = new Queue();
while (test) {
    test.pop();
    if (test.size() < -1) {
        // just to get you out of the loop while testing
        alert("failed");
        break;
    }
}
alert("out:"+test);
```

Place alerts inside toString() and valueOf() to see that they don't get triggered by the conditional `while (test) {}`.

Comment: Without further testing I'd: You are wrong. It is possible if your pop() returns values as long as there are any, and if not destructs the object via obj = undefined or null.

Comment: Emm... What? )) This is not a real queue, of course. This `pop()` method does not pop anything from anywhere. It is there only to emulate the behaviour.

Comment: I mean, I tested it, and it does what I intended. The code may look dumb, but the whole point here was to test whether something gets triggered to evaluate object in `while(object)` clause. And the answer is no. Hence, I conclude, that the answer to the initial question is no.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an object? Why not use an array?

```
var queue = [array,of,things,to,do];
while (queue.length) {
    var todo = queue.pop();
    //do something to todo
}
```

Comment: I was using queue as an example - the real object is more complicated than that. Instead of queue it would be better to think along lines of it being a heap.

Comment: An empty array is a truthy value (as is a non-empty one), so that's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyClass = function(){

   this.CanOperate; 
   //value should be false when nothing can be done with this class instance
};


Use var obj = new MyClass();

while (obj.CanOperate) { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: See my related answer to using custom objects. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401601/448232    Disclaimer : Might not be directly helpful to your problem.

Comment: I guess my question was not clear enough. What I was hoping to ask if it is possible to define my class so that the second code would work without changes. :) I will try to clarify my question.

Comment: @Macobo: A reference to an object can return a "falsey" value only when set to `null` or `undefined`. As far as I can see, what you're trying isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you Robin - the comments here (albeit in a run-about way) explained this to me previously.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these will work:

**Destroy the Queue thus meeting the conditional requirement**

```
var queue = new Queue();
while (queue) {
  queue.size() ? queue.pop() : queue = null;  
}​
```

**Manually break out of the loop**

```
var queue = new Queue();
while (queue) {
  queue.size() ? queue.pop() : break;  
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function Queue() {}
Queue.prototype.toString = function() {
    // I'm using "this.queue" as if it were an array with your actions
    return !!this.queue.length;
};

var queue = new Queue();

// Populate queue

while ( queue ) {
    queue.pop();
}
```

The idea is to override `toString` to return not some string value, but rather a boolean.

Comment: The idea is pretty straightforward. The only bad thing is that it doesn't work (tested in FF and IE). I just tryed to create a class with `toString()` and `valueOf()` overriden in prototype. And neither of them seems to get called with `while (test) {}` clause.